# variable name as input for string use in php

Tags: php, mysql

Let's assume we want to give an input so that the program understands a variable we use. For example:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];

$p='...';

$sqlLogin= "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username=' ".$name." ' ";
```

if the input is `{$p}` , then the variable is not printed , instead the result is:

```
SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username='{$p}'
```

Is there a way for the program to understand {$p} as a variable (through input), like it does 
when we write

```
 $sqlLogin= "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username='{$p}'";
```

Comment: Just use prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: If `$p='XX';` then `" username='{$p}'"` becomes `" username='XX'"`. Or do you mean that `$name` has a value like `{$p}`. Then, omg dont want to say it, but then you can/have to use `eval()` on it. Dam it, i have sayed it.

Comment: What you want is achievable using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) but using the user input as variable name is a sure recipe for disaster.

Comment: No. Because `$name` will be a string of `{$p}`, and you won't be able to use it as a variable, its strictly a string. Usage of "variable variables" or executing it server-side might do what you're asking, but both those are **bad approaches and you should not do it** unless you *really* know what you're doing - there are too many security holes that can be exploited with that.

Comment: i don't want to change the code , only the input .

Answer (score 0):

Just to prove the concept here:

```
$name = '{$p}';

$p= 'MYVALUE';

echo eval("return \"".eval("return 'SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE username =\'$name\'';").'";');
```

Result:

> SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE username ='MYVALUE'

But try to avoid the use of `eval();`

Have a nice day;

Comment: SO people are so strange. It would be nice if downvoters have too comment when downvoting. What the heck. It *is* working, it *is* just a prove of concept, it does what the OP want, and i warn not to use it. So much to learn from some lines of code. but whatever

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use the eval() function because the variable is a string, so the code is treating it as such, but you want the string to be ran as code.

`eval("$sqlLogin = \"SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username='{$p}'\"")`